# Scroll only FrameLayout in AppBarLayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

My app has 3 layouts into AppBarLayout: Toolbar, FrameLayout and LinearLayout. When I scroll up the NestedScrollView it's necessary to hide FrameLayout but Toolbar must stay in his place and LinearLayout must be under the Toolbar. At the current situation, nothing is scrolled.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorFilters"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/userinfo_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/navigation_tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
           />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:text="@string/fully_text"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code, it will work for sure
mold it according to your need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0.0dip"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/black"
            android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/close_activity"
                    android:layout_width="?actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:tint="@color/my_green"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
                    tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

                <TextView
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:text="Profile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:scrollingCache="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:text="@string/fully_text"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

hope it helps

happy coding :)

any problem

leme know

Comment: Where should be frameLayout? If an app has 2 layouts it's not a problem, but I asked about 3 layouts, the situation will differ

Comment: keep only one view inside toolbar. lets say you keep a linearlayout and after that keep whatever iu want to keep inside that linearlayout

Comment: @Delphian have a look at my code how i have used linearlayout inside toolbar to plae othr views in it

Comment: You have LinearLayout into Toolbar it means that the layout will have the same animation like toolbar. But I want different animation for layouts. I need pinned Toolbar, hide FrameLayout (when scrolling up) and LinearLayout must scrolling too that it will be placed under the Toolbar.

Comment: use any layout inside linearlayout i said and apply any animation u want

Comment: Ok, can you give me an example with 3 layouts and animation which is described above? Is it necessary to create animation manually or we can use advantages of coordinatorlayout?